# Is it illegal to allow a minor to participate in a site satisfaction survey?

Tags: internet, data-protection, minor, online, data-storage

Consider some imaginary website, run by a US legal entity - let's call it Whack Stove Reflow - has registered users, some of whom are under 18. This imaginary website wants to take a community satisfaction survey. Would it be illegal for the site to ask its sub-18-yro participants to take the survey, or to not-prevent them from participating?

Also, same question, but if the survey containing optional questions regarding personal details such as gender and racial background.

PS - If this *may* be illegal, please try to characterize the conditions/thresholds of legality.

Comment: Did you have a jurisdiction in mind?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim: I'm not entirely sure, since the website has users in many countries, but edited to say it's a US legal entity.

Comment: Good question. I assume that as an adult I automatically consent to you using the data in some reasonable way, as long as nobody forces me to take the survey. A minor should be able to change their mind and withdraw consent later. That could practically be difficult.